# How to share Authentication token between app in Firebase 3.0?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In older version of Firebase we can obtain authenticated token for sharing between our app, extensions.

But when upgrade to Firebase 3.0, that function doesn't work anymore.
I've use getTokenWithCompletion: on FIRUser, then in my App Extension I call signInWithCustomToken:completion: with token i just obtained. But Firebase return an error with messgage:

> Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17000 "The custom token format is
>   incorrect. Please check the documentation." UserInfo=0x799b6010
>   {error_name=ERROR_INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN, NSLocalizedDescription=The
>   custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.}

How to get authenticate token from FIRUser to re-authenticate it in my App Extension?

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/R4YUKBpn2lY

Comment: I am also getting same problem.. :(

Answer (score 4):

`signInWithCustomToken` is meant to be used with your own tokens minted on your own server (read more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server#create_a_custom_token)).

The best way for you to bootstrap a session between different components of your application will be to, at sign-in time, share the user's credential and perform the bootstraping across all your components.

For example, if you are using [Facebook login](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/facebook-login#authenticate_with_firebase), when your retrieve the facebook access token, you would have to share it from your app to your extension, and then call signInWithCredential with the same token in both your main app and extension.

There is currently no way to sign in a user into a Firebase app with the v3.X SDKs from another Firebase app instance.

Comment: How about guest authentication?, how can I share credential to my app extension?

Comment: That is currently not supported natively by the SDK unfortunately - albeit it's on the list of things we want to support in the near term). My best recommendation at this point would be to keep using the v2.X SDKs if this is a feature critical to your application and you cannot solve this issue in another way.

Comment: From a web/js perspective at least it seems possible to use the v2 SDK for initial sign-in, and then use that token via the REST  `https://auth.firebase.com/v2/{namespace}/sessions` to get another token that works with v3.x SDKs in `signInWithCustomToken`. 

I found this via the https://github.com/firebase/firebase-auth-migration-helpers.

Any new/plans where to vote or follow on this issue @alfongj? (allowing only passing a token from 'app signon' to other parts of the application (web, rest api etc))

Comment: @alfongj Has this changed at all since your answer? I managed for a short time this afternoon to share a logged in FIRUser between my app and extension by just enabling keychain sharing between the two, however I haven't been able to get it working again since.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem this morning when upgrading to the latest version of Firebase on Android.
To fix the problem I had to update the Firebase Server SDK to version 3.0+

This is a Java backend implementation, but the same applies for NodeJS as well.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
  <artifactId>firebase-server-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>[3.0.0,)</version>
</dependency>
```

In the new Firebase Server SDK you have to initialize your Firebase app first using a generated JSON file.(Found under permissions in your new Firebase console) Then you can generate the JWT token.

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream("path/to/json/file.json"))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/")
                .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

String token = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken("userID");
```

A token generated this way worked allowed me to use the new signInWithCustomToken() method.

You can read more here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error as the OP. I am assuming that you are using a service account email and private key during token generation on your server. The token my server generated was successful on [http://jsfiddle.net/firebase/XDXu5/](http://JSFiddle). However, my app would give the same error.

In the end, it turned out that I was signing it using "HS256" (which is what I was using in my existing token generation - pre firebase 3.0). When I changed it to "RS256" instead, the token generated works in the app.

Hope that helps.