# Firebase share authenticated user between apps (Single Sign On)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have two webs app, **app A** and **app B**. Both use firebase and firebaseUI libs...and not the firebase admin lib since they are both public facing.

I can login to either A or B without an issue and get a JWT token.

I would like to have a single sign on (either app A or app B) and have the user be logged in both **app A** and **app B** by sharing the JWT token between the apps.

Is it possible to send the JWT token from **app A** to **app B** and have the **app B** authenticate (log in) the user without the user having to manually log in on **app B**?

I see that there is a method to sign in with a custom token:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)
```

But using firebase's JWT token I get:

```
[Error]: The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.] {
  code: 'auth/invalid-custom-token',
  message: 'The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.'
}
```

Is there a method to sign in with the current JWT token (not a custom one)?

Comment: could you please add anything that could help me solve this , iv been looking into this as well

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure both the apps A and B should belong to the same firebase project.

It seems the token is cached one and has expired. Please refresh the token for it to be re-used.

Comment: You can also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337714/how-to-share-authentication-token-between-app-in-firebase-3-0?rq=1

Comment: I appreciate you taking a look at the question but what you propose doesn't apply to the original q. The apps belong to the same firebase project and the token is a valid one (no need to refresh). The issue is sharing that valid token between the apps and having firebase automatically log in both apps with the same token without the user having to do anything on their end